# Remove underline of links in email signature in Gmail

Tags: css, email, outlook, gmail

I have tried every suggested approach and I cannot get rid of the blue underline of the links of my Outlook signature on Gmail desktop (it's fine on Gmail Android app).

I tried to apply `text-decoration: none !important` to all links, on the `<a>` tag and on the `<span>` tag. I also tried to overwrite Gmail (using class .ii).

I tried each of them separately but none of them work, I always get a blue underline no matter what I do.

```css
a:link {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

.ii a[href] {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="color:red; text-decoration:none">
    <span style="color:red; text-decoration:none";>text</span>
</a>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Tried your code, did not find blue underline. Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: same as @orabis

Answer (score 1):

So for gmail in order to pick up the an actual style for a hyperlink anchor (  ) you have to use the following inline css to set the colour and remove the underlining : 
`style="color: #FF0000; text-decoration:none; cursor:text; pointer-events: none;"`

This is how a complete tag would look like :
`<a href="http://www.google.com/" style="color: #FF0000; text-decoration:none; cursor:text; pointer-events: none;">Click here to go to Google</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified as below. There are a lot of unnecessary/unused styles. However, even with your code, the underline was not there. One more thing, try as possible to avoid !important, and instead rely on [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```css
.info-link{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="info-link"><span>text</span></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I must do something wrong.

Here is the code I am using:

<head><style>

.info-link{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:red;
}

</style></head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="info-link"><span>text</span></a>
</body>

I still get the issue.
I use my HTML file as an signature on Outlook and when I send an e-mail to Gmail, my link is still underlined in blue.

Any idea what I do wrong ?

Comment: Tried the code, did not have a problem. Here is what I did. I saved the content in an html file. Then, opened the html file, copied its rendered content into the clipboard. Then, I went to my gmail signature and pasted the rich link. The gmail prompted me to update the link, I hit change, in order to make sure that the url will validly refer to google. That's it, and did not find any underlines.

Comment: The issue may be with my Outlook then as I try this as a signature on Outlook.
It works perfectly fine on Oulook and on Gmail Android App but people on Gmail desktop see those ugly blue underline

Comment: This kind of simplification does not work in many email clients, especially not when sending with Outlook, css have to be inline, and `text-decoration` is not valid on `<a` you have to resort to `<span style="display: inline-block"`

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap library:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and add class="btn" in your anchor tag as:

```
<a class="btn" style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.google.com"><span>text</span></a>
```

Comment: I still get a blue underline: https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/991776signaturegmail2.jpg

I assume something is wrong in my setup but cannot figureit out. 

I just use your exact code in a HTML file I use for my signature on Outlook and the link is underlined when I send an e-mail using this signature to Gmail desktop. (on gmail Android app, your solution works perfectly)

Comment: send me your code snapshot to my mail id `imsumit0303@gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just sent you an e-mail

Comment: apply edited code as it is, what I did today. this will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

try this
use **CSS text-decoration Property**

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a { text-decoration : none; color : #000; }
-->
</style>
```

learn more about [CSS text-decoration Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove link underlining in email signatures in Gmail **by using a non-Chrome browser to set up the signature**, as follows:

1. Open your email signature **in a non-Chrome browser**, e.g. Firefox
2. Copy the signature - select all (Ctrl/Cmd-A), copy (Ctrl/Cmd-C)
3. Open Gmail - **again in a non-Chrome browser** (this is important - Chrome's user-agent stylesheet will interfere if you perform this step using Chrome)
4. Select the Settings (gear) icon > See all settings
5. Paste the signature into the email signature field
6. Save

You can now open Gmail in Chrome and compose a new email. The email signature should appear without the underlined links. If it doesn't work the first time (as it for me), delete the draft, reload Gmail and compose again.